# jQuery - How to get the .change() event to fire

Tags: jquery, onchange

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get the `change()` event to fire.

**JS:**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Textbox_Positions').change(Function())
           alert("test");
   })
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input id="Textbox_Positions" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 205px" />
```

Comment: Is this your first event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

`Function` should be `function`

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Textbox_Positions').change(function(){
           alert("test");
        });
   });
</script>
```

plus you have a syntax error by not correctly create a block using `{..}` for you functions code..

---

The whole `function() {/*code here*/}` needs to go inside the `change` parenthesis.

```
$('#Textbox_Positions').change(function(){/*code*/});
```

Just as you do for `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
        $('#Textbox_Positions').on("change", function ()
        {
           alert("test");
        });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did miss the {} on the function that encloses the alert.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Textbox_Positions').change(function(){
           alert("test");
        });
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers for hooking up an element to the change function are correct, but the answer to your question, if you want to test that it works is `$('#Textbox_Positions').trigger('change');`.

I have used the changed event in this way to propagate changes through nested, jquery'ed elements that require an internal update() function to fire when the layout changes on one of their descendants.